# trying to understand recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion

Im trying to understand how the following C code works underneath:

```
int factorial(int n) {
   int result;
   if(n==0){
       result=1;
    }else{
       result = n * factorial(n-1);
   }
   return result;
}
```

I understand that the output is the factorial of n. I guess Im trying to understand if this example of recursion is using the if statement as the cause for recursion. And can recursion for this also be performed with a for loop instead of the if? Or am I missing the point completely?

Comment: It's recursive because the function calls itself.

Comment: As @rici pointed out it's recursion because the function call itself, just to add on that the first part of if statement is used to end the recursion while the else part keeps it going.

Comment: The `if` is necessary to provide a base, *non*-recursive case (when `n` is zero).  Without that, how would it ever stop recursing?

Comment: Recursion can many times, but not always, be implemented via a loop. Factorial is usually used as an introduction to recursion because it is so simple.

Comment: The factorial can certainly be computed iteratively (e.g. via a `for` loop) instead.  In fact, the iterative alternative is *much* better than the particular recursive implementation you present.

Comment: In order to understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

Comment: The problem is that your code is too complicated. Try simpler code: `int fact_iter(int n, int acc){return n ? fact_iter(n-1, acc*n) : acc;} int factorial(int n) {return fact_iter(n, 1);}`

Comment: Can somebody prove an example of recursion without a loop? Maybe that will help me understand this better.

Comment: This _is_ an example of recursion without a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guess Im trying to understand if this example of recursion is using the if statement as the cause for recursion.

The *cause* for recursion is the function calling itself.  The `if (n == 0)` condition tells us when to *stop* recursing.

If we call `factorial(3)`, the recursion looks something like this:

```
factorial(3):
  return 3 * factorial(2): -----------+
     return 2 * factorial(1); ------+ |
       return 1 * factorial(0); --+ | |
         return 1;                | | |
       1; <-----------------------+ | |
     2; <---------------------------+ |
  6; <--------------------------------+
```

> And can recursion for this also be performed with a for loop instead of the if?

You wouldn't use a loop in this case - recursion is a type of loop in and of itself.

For *computing* factorials, Fibonacci numbers, etc., I will argue that an iterative algorithm (loop) is superior to a recursive algorithm:

```
int factorial_iter( int n )
{
  int result = 1;
  while ( n )
    result *= n--;
  return result;
}
```

as there's very little overhead compared to making `n` separate function calls.  However, factorials are easier to *express* using recursive definitions:

```
n! = n * n-1!, 0! = 1
```

so you often see it used as an example of recursion in programming.  Indeed, languages like [Haskell](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell) pretty much follow the mathematical notation:

```
factorial :: Int -> Int
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = n * factorial( n - 1 )
```

Anything you can solve recursively you can solve iteratively, although some solutions (quicksort, tree traversals, etc.) are much easier to implement recursively.

For example, an inorder tree traverse can be written as

```
 /**
  * Perform an inorder traversal by
  * visiting the left subtree, then the root,
  * then the right subtree.
  */
 void inorder( node_type *t )
 {
   if ( !t )
     return;

   inorder( t->left );
   do_something_with( t->data );
   inorder( t->right );
 }
```

This is *much* simpler than trying to write a loop to visit all the nodes in the right order.

Comment: It should also be noted that in your iterative example the possible error (integer overflow causing wrap around) is much better than the recursive error (stack overflow causing a crash).  Additional error checking can be added to detect whenever the step result < step of result-1 (with unsigned int) so that you can know to throw away the answer.

Comment: A tail-recursive expression combines the advantages of recursion (invariants are never, even temporarily, broken) and iteration (constant storage, provided a reasonable compiler is used).

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like this:

- The factorial of 5 is (5 * factorial of 4)
- The factorial of 4 is (4 * factorial of 3)
- The factorial of 3 is (3 * factorial of 2)
- The factorial of 2 is (2 * factorial of 1)
- The factorial of 1 is 1

This is what you code is doing. When its asked for `fact(1)` it returns 1. Otherwise it returns n times `fact(n-1)`; repeat (recurse) as needed